# Bash test for capturing # (hash) character

Tags: bash, replace

How do I capture/escape `#` in a `test`?  I'm trying to use the clever answer from [How to reference captures in bash regex replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624969/how-to-reference-captures-in-bash-regex-replacement) to color everything after a `#` green

```sh
foo='hello # world'
foo="$([[ $foo =~ (#.*) ]] && echo -e ${foo/$BASH_REMATCH/\\e[32m${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\\e[0m} || echo $foo)"
echo -e $foo
```

I have tried using `(#.*)`, `(\#.*)`, and `(\\#.*)`.  The first two apparently successfully test `hello # world`, but don't replace it correctly...?

```sh
[[ $foo =~ (#.+) ]] && echo -e "${foo/$BASH_REMATCH/! ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} !}"
# prints: hello # world

[[ $foo =~ ( #.+) ]] && echo -e "${foo/$BASH_REMATCH/! ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} !}"
# prints: hello!  # world !
```

As seen above, if I precede the `#` with a space, it works fine, but I want a generic solution, and lookbehinds don't appear to work.

I can get this to work using sed, but for my purposes, it's very slow (on the order of seconds).  I'm sure there's a faster way that I could do this using sed, but I'd really like a vanilla bash solution.

Comment: Have you tried quoting it yet?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't match anything in that case.

Comment: What's the purpose of the command substitution?

Comment: ...if your goal is speed, you should try to avoid any fork operations.

Comment: As opposed to replacing `echo -e ` with `foo=`?  It's a remnant of a failed experiment.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/0ar6kO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo='hello # world'
esc_start=$'\e[32m'
esc_end=$'\e[0m'
 
if [[ $foo =~ (#.*) ]]; then
  foo="${foo/"$BASH_REMATCH"/"${esc_start}${BASH_REMATCH}${esc_end}"}"
fi
```

Comment: I copied and pasted that and got nothing

Comment: ‍♀️ I didn't `echo $foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider replacing bash-native text replacement with sed which is more suitable for complex strings.

```
foo="hello # world" char='#' foo=$([[ $foo =~ (($char).*) ]] && echo -e $( echo $foo | sed "s/$BASH_REMATCH/\\\\e[32m${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\\\\e[0m/") || echo $foo); echo -e $foo
```

Comment: There's a major performance impact that comes with using `sed` here: It's faster once it's running, but _much_ slower to start up; starting a copy of `sed` just to process a single line is basically always counterproductive.

Comment: Also, note that `echo -e $foo` is several flavors of buggy. `echo -e "$foo"` is unreliable -- its behavior can be modified by both compile-time and runtime configuration, which is not true of the POSIX-compliant equivalent `printf '%b\n' "$foo"` -- and `echo -e $foo` additionally has the bugs described in [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: ...for more details on the `printf`-vs-`echo` thing, see the excellent answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) over at [unix.se].